# How does python-hypothesis shrink a deferred strategy

Tags: python, python-hypothesis, property-based-testing

I am at the moment implementing PBB for Matlab and am somehow influenced by hypothesis.

I do not understand how hypothesis handles the shrinking of deferred strategies.
In the documentation there is the code snippet

```
import hypothesis.strategies as st
x = st.deferred(lambda: st.booleans() | st.tuples(x, x))
x.example()
>>> (((False, (True, True)), (False, True)), (True, True))
```

Now, this example should most likely shrink by reducing the depth of recursion. But, how does hypothesis know how to manipulate the lambda such that the example gets shrunk?

---

Question after answer of DRMacIver:

- Is hypothesis storing which choices belong to which strategy? E.g.: `(False,(False,False))` can be constructed as `10010000` (depth first). If we take the subsequence `01` (where the first `0` belongs to the strategy `booleans` instead to `tuples` now) we would get the example `True`, which probably does not count as a shrinked version of the former.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Shrinking a deferred strategy works the same as shrinking any other strategy, because shrinking in Hypothesis works uniformly on an underlying representation rather than needing to know much of anything about the strategies being used.

Instead of manipulating the generated values, Hypothesis modifies the choices used to construct them. You can think of this as making a series of coin flips. e.g. `(True, False)` might be generated by the sequence `10100` which is `1` (pick the second branch of the `|`), followed by `01` which picks the first branch then generates a `True` and `00` which picks the first branch then generates a False. We could reduce `(True, False)` to `True` by replacing `10100` with `01` or to `False` by replacing it with `00` both of which we can find as subsequences of the original sequence of choices.

If you want to know more about this you can read the paper about it (or watch the talk): https://2020.ecoop.org/details/ecoop-2020-papers/13/Test-Case-Reduction-via-Test-Case-Generation-Insights-From-the-Hypothesis-Reducer

> Is hypothesis storing which choices belong to which strategy? E.g.: (False,(False,False)) can be constructed as 10010000 (depth first). If we take the subsequence 01 (where the first 0 belongs to the strategy booleans instead to tuples now) we would get the example True, which probably does not count as a shrinked version of the former.

No, Hypothesis doesn't have any particular notion of "ownership" of choices and considered `True` to be a perfectly valid shrink of `(False, (False, False))`! It is after all considerably smaller and simpler.

Comment: Please see my "edited question" too, if possible.

Comment: If you're planning on implementing Hypothesis-like PBT, I recommend starting with a port of https://github.com/DRMacIver/minithesis